# Replace image src in php using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I want to replace a string that contains image tag 
like this

```
img src="images/Selection_005.png"
img src="images/Selection_006.png"
```

into this

```
img src="/documents/20143/0/Selection_005.png"
img src="/documents/20143/0/Selection_006.png"
```

Ii just want to modify the path of the images.
How can I make it in php using regex?

Can I have a sample code?

Comment: Why regex? It's a simple str_replace you need. And you should include your attempts in your question.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own or do you just need/want the free sample code?

Comment: Everyone finding this question probably searches for `$string = preg_replace('(src="(.*?)")','src="newimage.png" data-echo="$1"', $string);`

Answer (score 1):

Use str_replace instead when it's a static "find", it will be much faster and require less RAM.

```
$arr =['img src="images/Selection_005.png"',
       'img src="images/Selection_006.png"'];

$find = "images";
$replace ="/documents/20143/0";

Foreach($arr as $link){
    Echo str_replace($find, $replace, $link) ."\n";
}
```

Output

```
img src="/documents/20143/0/Selection_005.png"
img src="/documents/20143/0/Selection_006.png"
```

https://3v4l.org/0ZT9e

Comment: For clarification

I have a string like this

$content = '<p><img src="/images/Selection_004.png" alt="" width="199" height="120" />
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<img src="documents/Selection_005.png" alt="" width="199" height="120" /></p>';

I want to find all the images in that string
and replace the path of the image
that is what i want to happen

Comment: @FalconRyu Yes?

Comment: so i was thinking if i have to use regex for this

Comment: Still no need for regex. Read the manual for str_replace. http://php.net/str_replace Example: https://3v4l.org/T33EP

Comment: Thanks! It work for me although i made some changes
https://3v4l.org/bTSgD

Comment: Yet again your overdoing your code. You don't need all that. The code will only run slower and it will not make your code any better.